# Pass value from one select to another select

Tags: jquery

First of all I have 3 radio buttons like:

```
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov" value="P">Prov
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="user" value="U">Usu
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc" value="S">Suc
```

and I have two select lists like:

```
<select id="lst1"></select>
<select id="lst2"></select>
```

Now I disable `lst2` if radio button with value `"S"` is clicked as:

```
var responsable = Object.freeze({
  PROVEEDOR: "P",
  USUARIO: "U",
  SUCURSAL: "S"
});

$('input:radio[name="editList"]')
  .click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === responsable.SUCURSAL) {
      $('#lst2').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#lst2').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

But now I want to select one value of `lst1` and automatically pass it to `lst2`(disable select), I try to do it like:

```
$('#lst1').change(function() {
  if ($('input:radio[name="editList"]').val() === responsable.SUCURSAL) {
  $('#lst2').val($(this).val());
  }
});
```

But It don´t works, there is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wufz7yv/9/) of what I´m trying to do. Regards

Comment: When you debug, put a breakpoint in the lst1 change and check the value of $('input:radio[name="editList"]').val(). I think you need to use $('input:radio[name="editList"]:checked').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by @Simon in the comments first you need to properly find the correct checked radio button:

```
$('input:radio[name="editList"]:checked').val();
```

After that it is immediately clearing your selected value because every time the value of `lst1` changes you are repopulating the options of `lst2`. I fixed it by adding an `if` around `getlst2` but not sure that is what works best for you:

```
function getlst2(sender) {

  // sender: jQuery Object which called this method.
  if ($("#lst2").find('option').length == 0) {
    sender.addClass("changed");
    $("#lst2").getJSONCatalog({
      url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
      valueProperty: "id",
      textProperty: "value"
    });
  }
}
```

It also only works from the second change and on because by the time the change event fires the first time there are no options in `lst2` yet. You can fix this by having your jQuery function return a promise. Like so:

Create a deferred immedaitely:

```
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
```

Return the promise at the end:

```
return dfd.promise();
```

Resolve the promise after you populate options:

```
var successfulResponse = function(data) {
    appendOptions(data);
    dfd.resolve("done");
    settings.onSuccess(data);
};
```

Then you can ask it to run another function after it completes:

```
$("#lst2").getJSONCatalog({
  url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
  valueProperty: "id",
  textProperty: "value"
}).then(
  function() {
    $("#lst1").change()
  }
);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wufz7yv/12/

Let me know if you have any questions! Good luck.

======================================

**Update from your comment:**

This happens because you are using a widget for the selectbox now. The options need to be refreshed on the widget after they are added. You can do this by destroying the widget and reinitializing it.

```
$("#lst1").select2("destroy");
$("#lst1").select2();
```

You should really continue using the promise code I gave you because it is handy in this situation too:

```
$("#lst1").getJSONCatalog({
  url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
  valueProperty: "key",
  textProperty: "value",
  onChange: getlst2
}).then(
  function() {
    $("#lst1").select2("destroy");
    $("#lst1").select2();
  }
);
```

Now we can tell the widget to update after options are changed.

And you will also need to update your code for updating the value to work with the widget properly:

```
$('#lst2').select2("val", $(this).val());
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/696/

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works great, but now I want to implement it using select 2, but it don´t works, select 2 block something when we are trying to repopulate select? there is  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/695/)

Comment: with select 2 it don´t works but if I don´t add it, it works

Comment: @Gerardo added an update at bottom of answer for you. If all this helped you please remember to select it as the answer please! =]

Comment: Great Answer! +1

Comment: Note.. I donpt know if select2 create a new instance if we use `$('#lst2').select2("val", $(this).val());` so we can change triggering option like:   `$('#lst1').val($(this).val()).trigger("change");`